# MediaPlayer with Internal Files

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to select an audio file from internal storage, which I then create a media player from.

```
public void openPressed(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, data.getData());
        player.start();
    }
}
```

All of this is in my main activity, but after selecting a file, the app crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/audio/media/29 }} to activity {com.malik.mixtape/com.malik.mixtape.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
            at com.malik.mixtape.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:65)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: And what does the error say? (The error in Logcat)

Comment: Here are the errors.

Comment: So why did your program attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference?

Comment: How is it null? I created it from the internal file's URI.

Comment: It's obviously null, because you got a NullPointerException by calling a method on it...

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: are you by any chance want to play mp3 file?

Comment: I'm not looking to play a file from my android project assets. I want to have the used select directly from the internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this instead, I am assuming that data.getData() returns the path to the file,

```
 MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);

    player.setDataSource(MyActivity.this, Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getData())));


  MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
  {
      /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) 
      {
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);    
        player.start();
      }
  };
```

Comment: No, it returns a Uri, so you don't need all that casting. Otherwise, I've tried this with the same results. No success.

Comment: I call this to play video files from local storage,the only difference is I use the OnPrepared listener to call start since it takes a while to prepare the video and it is recommended to use it. So I am not sure why it will not work on an audio file. I will modify the code with the onPrepared listener

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with an Intent. When will this be called?